# Get Multiple XML children with same name with PHP

Tags: php, xml, nodes

I have an XML file that I am reading from, which gives match info.

Here is the file contents (well part of it to save wasting space)

```
<match>
<competition>Barclays Premier League</competition>
<date>Tuesday 2nd February 2016</date>
<time>19:45:00</time>
<status>Full Time</status>
<team>
     <side>home</side>
     <no>42</no>
     <name>West Ham United</name>
     <halfTimeScore>0</halfTimeScore>
     <score>2</score>
     <goal>Michail Antonio (58')</goal>
     <goal>Cheikhou Kouyate (85')</goal>
     <player>
         <shirtNo>5</shirtNo>
         <name>James Tomkins</name>
     </player>
     <player>
         <shirtNo>19</shirtNo>
         <name>James Collins</name>
         <cautioned>
             <minute>67</minute>
         </cautioned>
     </player>
</team>
<team>
     <side>away</side>
     <no>2</no>
     <name>Aston Villa</name>
     <halfTimeScore>0</halfTimeScore>
     <score>0</score>
     <player>
         <shirtNo>18</shirtNo>
         <name>Kieran Richardson</name>
     </player>
     <player>
         <shirtNo>38</shirtNo>
         <name>Jordan Lyden</name>
     </player>
</team>
<attendance>34914</attendance>
<venue>Upton Park</venue>
```

I am having problems when trying to get the 'Goal' information.

So far my code is:

```
$location = 'http://www.footballwebpages.co.uk/match.xml?match=15321';
$xml = @file_get_contents($location);
$httpcode = $http_response_header[0];
$httpcode = substr($httpcode, 9, 3);

if ($httpcode==429) {
    break;
} else if ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) {
    $xmltext = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $comp = $xmltext->competition;
    $date = $xmltext->date;
    $status = $xmltext->status;

    $team_no = 0;
    foreach($xmltext->team as $update) {
        /** Grab Info */
        $team_side[$team_no] = $update->side;
        $team_id[$team_no] = $update->no;
        $team_name[$team_no] = $update->name;
        $team_ht_score[$team_no] = $update->halfTimeScore;
        $team_score[$team_no] = $update->score;

        if (isset($update->goal)) {
            $goalno = 0;
            foreach ($update->goal as $goal) {
                $goal[$team_no][$goalno] = $goal;
                $goalno ++;
            }
        }

        /* Grab Player Info */
        $playerinfo[$team_no] = "";
        foreach($update->player as $player) {
            $playerno = $player->shirtNo;
            $playername = $player->name;
            /* caution */
            if (isset($player->cautioned)) {
                $playercaution = $player->cautioned->minute;
            } else {
                $playercaution = "";
            }
        }
        $team_no ++;
    }
}
```

The part im sturggling with is:

```
if (isset($update->goal)) {
    $goalno = 0;
    foreach ($update->goal as $goal) {
        $goal[$team_no][$goalno] = $goal;
        $goalno ++;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: *"What am I missing"* ... You haven't specified what the actual problem is or what is currently being returned or if there are errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
if (isset($update->goal)) {
    $goalno = 0;
    foreach ($update->goal as $goal) {
        $goal[$team_no][$goalno] = $goal;
        $goalno ++;
    }
}
```

you perform a `foreach` loop through `$update->goal` SimpleXMLElement objects as `$goal`, then you assign this value to an array named `$goal`, but `$goal` is a SimpleXMLElement object, not an array.

Simply change the name of `$goal` array.

Comment: Oooops, I didn't see that one. Thanks